# How to select first row from a join that returns multiple rows on the primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, greatest-n-per-group, sql-server-2019, lateral-join

I have two tables that I am joining. They share a key. The `employee` table has one name per primary key but the `email` table has multiple emails per `employeeId`.

I want to only show the first email per employee. Presently I get multiple rows per employee because they have multiple emails. I am running SQL Server 2019.

Edit: first email as I see it would be the first email row that shows up in the join as SQL works through the query. I do not matter which email shows up. Only that no more than one email shows up. I hope that makes it clearer.

My current query:

```
Select Employee.PersonName, Email.Email
From Employee
left join on Employee.ID = Email.employeeId;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method uses a subquery:

```
select ep.personname, em.*
from employee ep
cross apply (
    select top (1) em.email 
    from email em   
    where em.employeeid = ep.id 
    order by em.email
) em
```

If you just want the email and nothing else, aggregation is also OK:

```
select ep.personname, 
    (select min(em.email) from email em where em.employeeid = ep.id) as email
from employee ep
```

Or:

```
select ep.personname, min(em.email) as email
from employee ep
left join email em on em.employeeid = ep.id
group by ep.id, ep.personname
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following tables:

1. **Employee** (Id, PersonName)
2. **Email** (Id, EmployeeId*, Email)

What you can do is to use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) partitioning by EmployeeId and ordering for Email Id:

```
   SELECT Employee.PersonName, Email.Email
     FROM Employee
LEFT JOIN (SELECT EmployeeId, Email, ROW_NUMBER(PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY Id FROM Email) RN) Email
          ON (Employee.Id = Email.EmployeeId)
    WHERE Email.RN = 1
```